# How to translate "I am French"

Tags: adjective, noun

I would like to know how to express one's citizenship in German. Whether one has to use a noun or an adjective. For example would you say

> Ich bin französich.

or

> Ich bin Franzose/Franzosin.

Likewise, would a girl say

> Ich bin deutsche.

or

> Ich bin Deutscher(in?).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"I am French" is:

> Ich bin Franzose/Französin.

Note that the female form uses an umlaut.

In the case of "I am German" you use the nominalized adjective. As a noun, it has to be uppercase, but it is inflected like an adjective.

> Ich bin Deutscher/Deutsche.

Comment: Agreed but normally you would say »Ich komme aus Deutschland«.